# Adding a new object or collection of objects to props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a React page that loads in a bunch of stuff from a redux store that uses saga middleware.

In this particular page, I want to load something new that is not passed in via props.

So I created a new reducer, action, and watcher for a new collection of uploaded profile photos.

Is there a way to load this new collection in that I set up without passing it as props?

Thanks!  :)

Here's my react function for that page:

```
export default function profileEdit(props) {
    //passed in as props
    const { stats, weapons, armor, readOnly } = props;

    //not passed in as props
    const { profilePics } = ??;

    return (
        <div></div>
    )
```

Comment: Perhaps explaining why you want to avoid using props would allow us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use props or context api to pass something to react component.

Since you have your pics in the redux store, the proper way is to wrap your component in `connect` function wrapper from `react-redux` and select the collection via `mapStateToProps`.

This way your data from redux store will get injected into your component's props so you can display them out.

here is an example: https://gist.github.com/markerikson/121c77a01c453466361a9c6434a08620